# There is already an object named 'PDBCompr' in the database

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops, temp-tables

I am using SQL server 2008. I want to insert data from a `temp table` to `database`. I am using `While loop` to insert data from temp table to database table. 
Now I am facing an issue:

> object already exist in the database.

```
 declare @rev as int  ,
    @sQuotationNo NVARCHAR(15),                                                                                      
    @sQRevNo int                                                                                               
    set @rev=(select top 1 QRevNo from PDBCompr Where QuotationNo='JCS_G1415_008' and QRevNo<>'3' order by QRevNo desc)   

    ;with cte as   
    (  
    SELECT    
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY QuotationNo) AS sSLNO,                                                 
     [CompanyCode] ,      
     [ProjectCode] ,   
     [PRevNo],  
     [CSlNo],      
     [ComprDescription] ,      
     [PID] ,      
     [RatingCode] ,      
     [Rating] ,      
     [StdSystems] ,      
     [BoosterSystems] ,      
     [GCUSystems] ,      
     [KOFSystems] ,      
     [HeaterSystems] ,      
     [OtherSystems] ,      
     [Comments] ,      
     [Currency1] ,      
     [UnitPrice1] ,      
     [Currency2] ,      
     [ExchRate2] ,      
     [UnitPrice2] ,      
     [Currency3],      
     [ExchRate3] ,      
     [UnitPrice3] ,      
     [CreateId] ,      
     [CreateDate] ,      
     [UpdateId] ,      
     [UpdateDate]                                                                                         
    from PDBCompr         
    where QuotationNo='JCS_G1415_008' and CompanyCode ='001' and QRevNo ='2'               
    and AddCmprId not in (select distinct AddCmprId from PDBCompr where QuotationNo='JCS_G1415_008' and CompanyCode ='001' and QRevNo ='3'   )  
    )      

    select * into #temp from cte   

    declare @cnt int , @loopCnt int=1 
    select @cnt =( select COUNT(*) from #temp)  

     while (@loopCnt<=@cnt)
     begin

    ;with cte2 as 
    (
     SELECT    
     sSLNO,                                                 
     [CompanyCode] ,      
     [ProjectCode] ,           
     (select Max(PRevNo)+1 from PDBCompr) [PRevNo],      
     (select Max(CSlNo) +1 from PDBCompr)[CSlNo],      
     [ComprDescription] ,      
     [PID] ,      
     [RatingCode] ,      
     [Rating] ,      
     [StdSystems] ,      
     [BoosterSystems] ,      
     [GCUSystems] ,      
     [KOFSystems] ,      
     [HeaterSystems] ,      
     [OtherSystems] ,      
     [Comments] ,      
     [Currency1] ,      
     [UnitPrice1] ,      
     [Currency2] ,      
     [ExchRate2] ,      
     [UnitPrice2] ,      
     [Currency3],      
     [ExchRate3] ,      
     [UnitPrice3] ,      
     [CreateId] ,      
     [CreateDate] ,      
     [UpdateId] ,      
     [UpdateDate]                                                                                        
      from #temp where sSLNO=@loopCnt
      )      

    select * into PDBCompr from cte2
    set @loopCnt= @loopCnt+1
    drop table  #temp
      end
```

Please help me to find a proper solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> select * into PDBCompr from cte2

in this line you are again making a table "PDBCompr", but in above code you are selecting records from this table it means its already exist.

so if you want to insert record in this table then you need to change your query like below:

> insert into PDBCompr select * from cte2